# error to translate jquery code to coffeescript code

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

this jquery code works fine for me in jquery format.

I want convert this jquery code to coffeescript code:

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {  
      $('.preview_browse img#thumb').attr('src', e.target.result).width(251).show();
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    $('.not_found_image_browse').hide();
  }
}
```

I get from http://js2coffee.org/ this code:

```
readURL = (input) ->
  if input.files and input.files[0]
    reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (e) ->
      $(".preview_browse img#thumb").attr("src", e.target.result).width(251).show()
    reader.readAsDataURL input.files[0]
    $(".not_found_image_browse").hide()
```

but when I enter this code in my project rails in post.js.coffee does not works fine for me.

I get in browser console this error:

```
readURL is not defined
onchange()onchange (line 2)
event = change
[Break On This Error]   
readURL(this);
```

This is my html code in my input file:

```
<input id="post_image" class="file required" type="file" onchange="readURL(this)" name="post[image]">
```

Comment: Where are you putting this JavaScript (CoffeeScript) code?  My guess is that `readURL` isn't in the global scope, so the `onchange` doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you using an `onchange` attribute when you have jQuery? Why not use jQuery to bind to the event?

Comment: Thank you @muistooshort can you write a example without onchange? Thank you!

Comment: @hyperrjas: `$('#post_image').change(function(){ readURL(this); });`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default all methods are defined in a closure in coffeescript so you have to explicitly put the method or object into the context of the window for it to be visible from the input's onchange attribute:

```
window.readURL = (input) ->
  if input.files and input.files[0]
    reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (e) ->
      $(".preview_browse img#thumb").attr("src", e.target.result).width(251).show()
    reader.readAsDataURL input.files[0]
    $(".not_found_image_browse").hide()
```

From http://coffeescript.org/

> Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function: `(function(){ ... })();` This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the `var` keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident.
>
> If you'd like to create top-level variables for other scripts to use, attach them as properties on **window**, or on the **exports** object in CommonJS. The **existential operator** (covered below), gives you a reliable way to figure out where to add them; if you're targeting both CommonJS and the browser: `exports ? this`